# Ruby returns syntax errors when referencing Net::SSH

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I've the following installed:

- Ruby version 1.8.7
- Net::SSH 2.10.0

I get the following error when I run my script:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `require': /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:199: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
              identity.merge(privkey_file: file)
                                          ^
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:266: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/net/ssh.rb:11:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/net/ssh.rb:11
        from test.rb:1:in `require'
        from test.rb:1
```

Do you know why this error has been thrown?

Comment: Thanks.  How can I determine which version of net-ssh is compatible with 1.8.7?

Comment: I've posted an answer. But beware that an old version might contain bugs fixed in newer releases. If it's possible upgrade to at least Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

The `net-ssh` gem doesn't support 1.8.7 anymore. The posted line uses [hash syntax that was added in 1.9](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_1_0/NEWS#L212-L213) (it's equivalent to `:privkey_file => file`). According to its [README](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/27fa9e3d9a459fb70afda68b0aa58d30ba2481d6/README.rdoc#ruby-18-support) the last version with 1.8 support is [2.5.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh/versions/2.5.1). You can install this old version with `gem install net-ssh -v 2.5.1` but make sure to remove the newer version you've installed.